# What bonus content is available for Simcity?

Tags: simcity-2013

I have a developing interest in the new Simcity game coming out next month, and I'm starting to poke around to get a sense of things.

I notice that if I preorder from Amazon, I get a "Heroes and Villains" pack.

[image]

I've also heard rumblings about bonus content in a Digital Deluxe edition. Are those two items all there is, or are there other preorder bonuses from other retailers floating about?

Comment: Since they are no doubt trying to push Origin. I would doubt they would offer any pre-order bonus since its a PC exclusive. Here is there page http://store.origin.com/store/ea/html/pbPage.SimcityNA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://store.origin.com/store/ea/html/pbPage.SimcityNA

From the link above

> Origin Exclusive Item—Plumbob Park: Just drop this scenic park
>   anywhere in your city and watch your Sims revel in the great outdoors!
>   Make your Sims happier, entice more to come to your city and improve
>   your rating as Mayor.
>
> Get access to world famous landmarks including the Eiffel Tower, Big
>   Ben or Brandenburg Gate! Placing landmarks will improve your land
>   value and attract tourists to visit, bringing more Simoleons to your
>   city! These landmarks transform the businesses, homes and vehicles in
>   your city to adopt the style and architecture of France, Great Britain
>   and Germany! Receive new missions and earn unique achievements!
>
> MORE TOURISTS Place the Eiffel Tower, Big Ben or Brandenburg Gate and
>   attract tourists to visit, increasing your land value and bringing
>   more Simoleons to your city!
>
> MORE TRANSPORTATION Transport your Sims more efficiently with an
>   exclusive Double Decker Bus station in Britain and high-speed rail in
>   Germany!
>
> MORE SERVICES Protect your Sims and increase your police presence with
>   an exclusive French police station!

The British, French, and German "extras" (Eiffel Tower, Big Ben, Brandenburg Gate, double-decker buses, high speed rail, French police station) are only available in the digital deluxe edition.

Plumbob Park and Heroes and Villains are included if you pre-order the normal edition (in other words, the "limited edition"). They are also included as part of the digital deluxe edition.